# MySQL paginated list of user ranking along with Ranking

Tags: sql, select, union, row-number, mysql-8.0

**MySQL V 8.0**

I need to get a paginated list of users with their ranks but should always add a specific user record (for example result should always have a user named 'Alex' record). Although I have unioned the queries and achieved the desired results but was thinking of overhead to the database by executing the same query twice. **Any suggestion for improvement is needed.**

```
create table userData (recordDate date ,userName varchar(10), score FLOAT);
```

```
insert into userData (recordDate, userName, score)
values
    ('2020/8/1','Chris', 78),
    ('2021/8/2','Aamir', 77),
    ('2021/8/3','Alex', 76),
    ('2021/8/1','Ali', 78);
```

**my solution**

```
select * from (
  
(select userName, score,
ROW_NUMBER() over (
order by score desc
)scores_rank
from userData
 limit 2)

union
  
(
select * from (
  select 
    userName, score,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (
    order by score desc
   )scores_rank
  from userData
) as singleUser
where userName="Alex")

) as main;
```

**The desired output is**

```
| userName | score | scores_rank |
| -------- | ----- | ----------- |
| Chris    | 78    | 1           |
| Ali      | 78    | 2           |
| Alex     | 76    | 4           |
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
set @page := 1;
set @limit := 2;

WITH ranks AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS score_rank
    FROM userData
) 
SELECT * 
FROM ranks 
WHERE score_rank BETWEEN (@page - 1) * @limit + 1 AND @page * @limit
   OR userName = 'Alex'
ORDER BY score_rank
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9e7c887166f922f7d4f5ae4476e7662)